# Android application with Samsung KNOX

Tags: android, mdm, samsung-knox

Is there any other Samsung API available for mobile device management, other than KNOX?
Also is it possible to integrate all the KNOX SDK (KNOX premium,KNOX VPN etc...) in to a single application?

As there is 1100 API in KNOX standard SDK,how can I get the Samsung KNOX standard sdk API list?

Comment: You need to contact Samsung for that. They also provide one EDM API, for that you need to contact them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is about to finding a tool/api.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have all KNOX APIs in one app.
All Samsung devices support standard Android administrator APIs and also Android for Work APIs (although in most cases if user activates KNOX, AfW may be disabled, unless your app designates KNOX container as AfW Managed Profile).

The standard API reference is here: https://seap.samsung.com/api-references/android-standard/reference/packages.html